# Export animated vertex color as .fbx

Tags: geometry-nodes, export, .fbx, vertex-colors

Is it possible to export animated vertex colours, here created with a geometry nodes graph?
The values animate from 1 to 0 and from 0 to 1, and the Color out is assigned to the colour attribute. The colour change is visible in the viewport.

[image]
[image]

But if I import the .fbx that I exported with the following settings I just get the first frame and it is not changing not the color changing:

[image]
[image]

Is this a limitation of the .fbx format or am I missing something? If it is a limitation would it work with alembics?
Thanks for helping out.

[image]